# Is $A \otimes _R R$ isomorphic to $A$ even when $R$ does not have an identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a ring (not necessarily with an identity). For a right $R$-module $A$, I know that the tensor product $A \otimes _R R$ is isomorphic to $A$, naturally, when $R$ has an identity. Does this also hold even when $R$ does not have an identity?

Comment: I did not come across tensor product over rings not containing identity.. Is it standard content?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik For example, Hungerford's Algebra defines tensor products without assuming that $R$ has an identity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If, say $R = c_{00}=\{f\colon \mathbb N\to \mathbb C\mid |\mathrm{supp}\, f|<\infty\}$ with pointwise multiplication and $A$ is *any* $\mathbb C$-vector space with *zero* $R$-module structure (meaning $a\cdot r:=0$ for every $a\in A$), then the relation of the tensor product forces
$$
a\otimes r = a\otimes r\cdot s_r = a\cdot r\otimes s_r = 0.
$$
Here the *support projection* $s_r\colon \mathbb N\to\mathbb C$ of $r$ is defined by
$$
s_r(i):=\begin{cases}
1,& r(i)\neq 0,\\
0, & r(i) = 0.\\
\end{cases}
$$